# А можно ли изминтить тип класс в python?

Tags: python

Как можно из объекта класса A сделать объект класса B? На с++ использовал приведение указателей.

```
A* a = new A;
B* b = (B*) a;
```

Можно ли также сделать на python?

P.S Есть объект класс `Html`. У него куча полей. Мне нужно чтобы у этого объекта были специальные методы которые есть у класса `HtmlParser`. Сам он является наследником `Html`. Для этого мне нужно просто как-то выполнить приведение типа из `Html` в `HtmlParser`.

Comment: Я не понял, зачем это нужно? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Вы можете написать функцию, принимающую один объект, а возвращающую другой. Аналогично функциям int, str, list и т.д.

Comment: Python - динамический язык с утинной типизацией, в нём приведение типов не нужно.

Comment: Странная логика. Почему HtmlParser - наследник Html? Ведь сам HtmlParser, видимо, не является Html по своей сути, а только предоставляет методы обработки Html.

Comment: У html есть свои методы и счётчики которые спокойно можно предать в HtmlParser. Поэтому используется наследование.